# I could not fix For each cell in range problem. Help is requested

Tags: excel, loops, foreach, conditional-statements, copy-paste

I have a to export information from A, B and D columns of Sheet 1 to to A, B, C columns in Sheet2, if AE contains 1. I made the following code from copying from stackoverflow site. It copies information from the all rows. I just want to copy only those rows which contain 1 in AE column. I need help. Thanks.

```
    Dim wsht1 as worksheet
   Dim Wsht2 as worksheet
   Dim c as range
   Dim Myrng as range
   Dim i as long
   Dim lRw2  as long
   Dim lRw1 as long


  wsht1 = ActiveWorkbook
  wsht1  = sheet (2)

  With WsHT1
    lRw2 = .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

   Set Myrng = Wsht1.Range("AE3", "AE" & LRW1)
   With Wsht1

  For Each c In Myrng.rows
    For i = 4 To LRW1

    With WsHT2
    lRw2 = .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

        If c = 1 Then
            .Range("A" & i).Copy WsHT2.Range("A" & lRw2).Offset(1, 0)
            .Range("B" & i).Copy WsHT2.Range("B" & lRw2).Offset(1, 0)
            .Range("D" & i).Copy WsHT2.Range("C" & lRw2).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        Next i
        Next c
    End With

   end sub
```

Comment: Where do you `Set MyRng`?

Comment: It is AE column. My apology for confusion. I copied part of the Macro and Missed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code:

```
Sub DataCopy()

    Debug.Print "RUNNING SOUBRUTINE"

    'Declarations.
    Dim WksWorksheet01 As Worksheet
    Dim WksWorksheet02 As Worksheet
    Dim RngTrigger As Range
    Dim RngDestination As Range
    Dim LngCounter01 As Long
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim LngColumn01 As String
    Dim LngColumn02 As String
    Dim LngColumn03 As String

    Debug.Print "DECLARATIONS COMPLETED"

    'Setting variables.
    Set WksWorksheet01 = ActiveSheet 'better to give the specific sheet name here
    Set WksWorksheet02 = Sheets("Foglio2") 'better to give the specific sheet name here
    Set RngTrigger = WksWorksheet01.Range("AE3", WksWorksheet01.Cells(WksWorksheet01.Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp))
    Set RngDestination = WksWorksheet02.Range("A3")
    LngColumn01 = 1
    LngColumn02 = 2
    LngColumn03 = 4

    Debug.Print "VARIABLE SETTING COMPLETED"

    Debug.Print "REPORT"
    Debug.Print "WksWorksheet01.Name = "; WksWorksheet01.Name
    Debug.Print "WksWorksheet02.Name = "; WksWorksheet02.Name
    Debug.Print "RngTrigger.Address = "; RngTrigger.Address
    Debug.Print "RngTrigger count value = "; Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(RngTrigger)
    Debug.Print "RngTrigger sum = "; Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(RngTrigger)
    Debug.Print "RngDestination.Address = "; RngDestination.Address
    Debug.Print "-------------"

    'Covering the whole RngTrigger.
    For Each RngTarget In RngTrigger
        'Checking if RngTarget contains 1.
        Debug.Print "RngTarget.Address = "; RngTarget.Address
        Debug.Print "RngTarget.Value = "; RngTarget.Value
        Debug.Print "Equal to 1? "; RngTarget.Value = 1
        If RngTarget.Value = 1 Then
            Debug.Print "Copied in row "; LngCounter01 + 1
            Debug.Print "Pre-existing data? "; RngDestination.Offset(LngCounter01, 0).Value <> ""; RngDestination.Offset(LngCounter01, 1).Value <> ""; RngDestination.Offset(LngCounter01, 2).Value <> ""
            'Copying data.
            RngDestination.Offset(LngCounter01, 0).Value = RngTarget.Offset(0, LngColumn01 - RngTarget.column).Value
            RngDestination.Offset(LngCounter01, 1).Value = RngTarget.Offset(0, LngColumn02 - RngTarget.column).Value
            RngDestination.Offset(LngCounter01, 2).Value = RngTarget.Offset(0, LngColumn03 - RngTarget.column).Value
            'Setting LngCounter01 for the next row.
            LngCounter01 = LngCounter01 + 1
        End If
        Debug.Print "-"
    Next

    Debug.Print "COPING COMPLETED"

End Sub
```

The code you posted didn't make much sense to me so i've basically created a new one. I'd suggest you to specify the name of the worksheets when you set them. I do not find Activesheet and sheets(2) really reliable (but i understand they might be necessary). Tell me if it works and/or if you need any explanation or improvement.

Comment: It copied very fast but copied all the records not only the ones with 1 in AE column.

Comment: Now that sounds strange. What do you have in column AE?

Comment: I have 1 or blank cell

Comment: Have you just copied the code and run it from the worksheet with the original data or did you integrated it in your code? Because i really see no reason why it shouldn't work. The only weak point for me is the worksheet set part.

Comment: I did not integrate. I created separate macro and run the code. the result is the same except it is very very fast. I opened file, changed the worksheet name and run the macro.

Comment: I've edit the code to print a report in the immediate window. Would you please run it and give me back the report?

Comment: if I had got report, I would share with you. Nothing happened. no window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212452/discussion-between-evil-blue-monkey-and-kailash).